# Do closed immersions preserve stalks?

Tags: schemes

This questions stems from an earlier confusion about the distinction between open and closed immersions between schemes.

I understand that an open immersion $U\to S$ can simply be read as an open subset $U\subseteq S$, as the only scheme structure you can put on $U$ which is in a sense "compatible" with the inclusion into $S$ is that given by restricting the structure sheaf of $S$ to $U$. Consequently the stalk $O_{U, u}$ for any $u\in U$ should be isomorphic to that same stalk $O_{S, u}$ for $S$.

I used to hold the false belief that closed immersions could similarly be identified with closed subsets. I now understand that a closed subset of a scheme can of course admit many different scheme structures - in fact, every closed subset can be considered a closed immersion from a reduced scheme! However, I wonder if at least some of that intuition is correct. Do closed immersions still preserve stalks?

I suppose this can be reduced to the affine case, so that we can simply ask "if $f:R\to T$ is a surjective morphism of rings, and $p\in Spec(T)$, then is it the case that $T_p \cong R_{f^{-1}(p)}$?" This does not appear obviously to be true.

A further question if this is false is ... what is the point of closed immersions? What is the intuition behind them? The course I am studying never really addressed such questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notation: $A^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ is the affine space of dimension $n$ over complex numbers, $P^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ is the projective space of dimension $n$ over complex numbers.

Take $X=\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{C}$, $Y=A^1_{\mathbb{C}}$, $f:X\rightarrow Y$ the inclusion of the origin. Let $x$ be the unique point of $X$. Then $O_{X, x}=\mathbb{C}$, $O_{Y, f(x)}=\mathbb{C}[x]_{(x)}$. These two can not be isomorphic because one is a field and the second is not.

You are asking what is the point of closed immersions if they do not preserve stalks. The point is that many morphisms of schemes people are interested in do not preserve stalks (just as the example above). The intutition is that a closed immersion is roughly the same as inclusion of a subset of your variety which is defined by polynomial equations–a very natural notion in my mind. As you say, when you pass from the world of varieties to the world of schemes you have to take into account the possible non-reducedness of your subsets (it is not too bad, however; if the source of the closed immersion is reduced, then your closed immersion [has](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0356) to factor through the "reduction" of the target).

One might ask: what are some good properties of of closed subschemes? For example, closed immersions [are](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01W5) proper (and the composition of proper morphisms [is](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01W3) proper) so for any scheme $S$, a closed subscheme of a proper $S$-scheme is a proper $S$-scheme. This obviously does not hold for open immersions (consider $A^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ as a subscheme of $P^1_{\mathbb{C}}$).

Another example is that a closed subscheme of an affine scheme [is](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01IH) also an affine scheme. An open subscheme of an affine scheme does not have to be affine: take $A^2_{\mathbb{C}}$ and consider the complement of the origin; this open subscheme has the same ring of global functions as $A^2_{\mathbb{C}}$ by [Hartogs lemma](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/031T); so if it were affine, it would be isomorphic to $A^2_{\mathbb{C}}$ and this is not the case becase e.g. their cohomologies are different). Note that in dimension 1, modulo some finiteness hypotheses, an open subscheme of an affine scheme [is](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09N9) affine. In general, the question of which open subschemes of an affine scheme are affine can be [pretty](https://mathoverflow.net/a/20792/137767) [interesting.](https://mathoverflow.net/a/47450/137767)

Now, if you required closed immersions to preserve stalks, you would not get a very wide class of morphisms (essentially only inclusions of connected components).

**Claim.** A closed immersion that preserves stalks, whose source is non-empty and whose target is integral is an isomorphism.

Proof. Let $i:X\rightarrow Y$ be the morphism in question. Pick a point in the image and choose its affine open neighbourhood $U=\mathrm{Spec}\,R$. $R$ is an integral domain because target is integral. $i$ [restricts](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01QO) to a map $\mathrm{Spec}\,R/I\rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\,R$ for some ideal $I$. Consider the stalks at our chosen point; projection $R_{\mathfrak{p}}\rightarrow (R/I)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ has to be an isomorphism. Note [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/502452/251240) $(R/I)_{\mathfrak{p}}\approx R_{\mathfrak{p}}/I_{\mathfrak{p}}$ so $I_{\mathfrak{p}}=0$. Now note that in an integral domain, localization of a non-zero module at a prime ideal can never give you zero; so $I$ is zero, therefore the image of $i$ is a closed set (by definition of closed immersion) that contains $U$, an open dense set (in an irreducible space, any non-empty open subset is dense). So $i$ is surjective. The requirement that $i$ preserves stalks implies that $i$ is flat. Surjective flat closed immersions are isomorphisms.

I am not sure if this claim holds if you assume that the target is only irreducible as opposed to integral.

**Claim.** A closed immersion locally of finite presentation that preserves stalks, has a non-empty source and a connected target is an isomorphism. In particular, a closed immersion that preserves stalks, has a non-empty source and a connected locally Noetherian target is an isomorphism.

Proof. As remarked above, such a morphism has to be flat. Flat morphisms locally of finite presentation [are](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01UA) universally open; so the image of our morphism is a non-empty clopen set so it has to be the whole target (by connectedness). Surjective flat closed immersions are isomorphisms. For the second sentence, note that closed immersions [are](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01T5) always of finite type and morphisms of finite type to a locally Noetherian scheme [are](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01TX) of finite presentation.

Note that the claim is not true without finite presentation assumption (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3182427/251240) for a counterexample with affine source and target).

As a general advice, I can recommend to you to read the textbook of Ravi Vakil. He is a well-known algebraic geometer and he spent many years writing and re-writing it so in my opinion, it is by far the best textbook in the field. It has really understandable explanations.

Comment: I have a further question. *Why* are closed immersions defined in a way that means a closed subset of a scheme can be a scheme in so many different ways? Varieties are not like this, as far as I can tell, and I don’t understand intuitively why Schemes should be.

Comment: @Nethesis the problem you mention, if I understand correctly, is not about closed immersions, it is about schemes in general. Why are schemes defined in such a way that two schemes having the same underlying set of points are not isomorphic (e.g. $X_{red}$ and $X$)? Well, one reason is many questions in deformation theory and intersection theory are most naturally addressed by using non-reduced schemes.

Comment: Take Bezout theorem about the number of intersections of plane curves: you either have to talk about "general" intersections or you have to step outside the world of varieties and embrace non-reducedness. Sure, you probably could define multiplicity of a point of intersection without defining schemes, but that it is some additional book-keeping while in the world of schemes you can just take the scheme-theoretic intersection.

Comment: or for example, if you want to talk about fibers of quasi-finite morphisms, you also can not stay in the world of varieties without additional headache (unless your morphism is unramified: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02G7).

Comment: The point being, if you really dislike schemes, and the only thing you care about are varieties, you could probably develop some theory but it would require a lot of additional book-keeping which ultimately will be equivalent to developing (parts of) scheme theory. You would also miss out on some funny moments (such as this intersection of the fundamental groups of manifolds and galois group: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tale_fundamental_group).

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/a/28594/137767 and https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/09/05/a-trivial-remark-about-schemes/ (the last one is written by a PDE and analytic number theory specialist, a person pretty distant from the Grothendieckian universe---but he also has found a way to appreciate non-reduced schemes from his own perspective).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't true, for a simple example you can take $R=\mathbb Z$, $T=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ and $f:R\to T$ to be the natural surjection (i.e. going modulo $p$). The only prime ideal of $T$ is the zero ideal $\mathfrak p=(0)$, and its pre-image under $f$ is $f^{-1}(\mathfrak p)=(p)$, so we find that $$R_{f^{-1}(\mathfrak p)}=\mathbb Z_{(p)}\quad\text{but}\quad T_{\mathfrak p}=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z,$$

these definitely are not isomorphic rings, for instance the one on the right is finite but the one on the left contains $\Bbb Z$.